# Deserialising loosely typed json with interfaces

Tags: c#, json.net

I have a rather loosely typed .json file which I'd like to deserialise.
The JSON is basically a condition list which controls a decision making.

```json
{
  "or" : [
     "and" : [
       {
         "bool" : {
          "expected" : true,
          "actual" : false
         }
       }, 
      {
        "bool" : {
         "expected" : false,
         "actual" : false
        }
      }
     ]
.
.
.
```

And the classes look like this:

```cs
    public class BoolCondition : ICondition
    {
        private readonly bool _expected;
        private readonly bool _actual;

        public BoolCondition(bool expected, bool actual)
        {
            _expected = expected;
            _actual = actual;
        }

        public bool Eval()
        {
            return _expected.Equals(_actual);
        }
    }

    public class AndCondition : ICondition
    {
        public ICondition[] Conditions { get; set; }

        public AndCondition()
        {
        }

        public bool Eval()
        {
            return Conditions.All(c => c.Eval());
        }
    }

    public class OrCondition : ICondition
    {
        public ICondition[] Conditions { get; set; }

        public bool Eval()
        {
            return Conditions.Any(c => c.Eval());
        }
    }
```

There is an interface called ICondition and the "or", "and", "bool", and other conditions are implementing this interface.
Of course, there can be any structure in this tree.

Is there any idea how I could deserialise this JSON?

Comment: You will need to use a custom `JsonConverter` to deal with this JSON.  See [How to parse JSON with a recursive structure representing a query](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51495326/10263) for a question similar to yours.

Comment: @BrianRogers Awesome, thanks